# how to display rows based on qty column values in rows

Tags: magento-1.9, database, query

I tried but not work in my code.
table is `sales_flat_order_item`

this is table

```
    item  | qty
    ------+------
    foo   |     5
    bar   |     3
```

But I want to output like this

```
   item   | qty 
    ------+-------+------
    foo   |     5
    foo   |     5
    foo   |     5
    foo   |     5
    foo   |     5
    bar   |     3
    bar   |     3
    bar   |     3
```

It means that it will create number of rows based on qty column values.
How can I do this functionality in magento.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();
        $item = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order_item');

        $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinCross(array('item' => $item), array('*'))
        ->where('item.qty_ordered >=1');
        //$collection->setOrder('name','ASC');      
        echo "<pre>";print_r($collection->getData()) ;
```

Comment: Why?  I don't understand the benefit you will gain from this.

Comment: you are right but this is my client  requirement.my client requires this type of functionality.plz help from this

Comment: I am unsure.  I would start with the array of 'item' and check the size.  Then use this and write a "for loop" in php.  Then put your "echo" statement inside of the for loop.

Comment: But i want to display this in my custom grid so i can not use for loop in grid.php

Comment: Why? It's still php.  Because it's custom?

Comment: So i want to achieve this by query

Comment: I will use order item collection in custom grid

Comment: So i want to display output like this in grid

Comment: I do not know how to use Magento ::Collection to accomplish this to edit a query.